# convert inheritance to templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, dry

I have C++11 project that uses inheritance. Here is small fragment:

```
class ICountable{
public:
        virtual ~ICountable(){}

        unsigned getCount() const{
                return _getCount();
        }

        bool isEmpty() const{
                return _getCount() == 0;
        }

private:
        virtual unsigned _getCount() const = 0;
};
```

Suppose we have some `LinkList` that inherits from `ICountable` and implements `_getCount()`. Then you can make function like this:

```
void doSomething(ICountable &countable){
    if (countable.isEmpty())
         doSomethingElse();
}
...
LinkList ll;
doSomething(ll);
```

This is all very good, but there must be another way to do all this:

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(T countable){
    if (countable.isEmpty())
         doSomethingElse();
}
...
LinkList ll;
doSomething(ll); // we do not even need to add <>
```

Template way is faster and probably easier to implement. `std::vector` and `std::deque` are like this as well.

However, how I can avoid code duplication - function `isEmpty()` must be pasted in all "list things".

I can imagine preprocessor `#include` or...

I can imagine `decorator`-like class that may implements all those sugar methods and to proxy the others:

```
template <typename T>
class List{
   T list;
public:
        unsigned getCount() const{
                return list.getCount();
        }

        bool isEmpty() const{
                return list.getCount() == 0;
        }

        ...
}
```

What is better inheritance or templates, if there will be no runtime polymorphism?

Is there better way to avoid code duplication?

Comment: You may be looking for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: isn't CRTP normal inheritance, just with template-d class? I am speaking of completely removing any base clases

Comment: `I am speaking of completely removing any base clases` Why? Are you charged a fee per each occurrence of class inheritance in your program?

Comment: :) no I just explore possibilities...

Comment: Making up arbitrary constraints from the start is a funny way to explore possibilities.

Comment: It sure looks like standard container, but is not.

Comment: Well, if you insist. You can make `isEmpty` a standalone function: `template <typename T> bool isEmpty(const T& x) { return x.getCount() == 0; }`. Or, you could make a traits class: `template <typename T> struct MyContainerTraits {static bool isEmpty(const T& x) { return x.getCount() == 0;} };` Either way, you'll have to change the implementation of `doSomething` accordingly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - thanks, your traits example was enlightenment for me, I tried to understand traits for months...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a C++ feature that has not been formally added to the standard (but has been in the works for quite some time) called [Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) that would essentially let you declare your `doSomething(T countable)` to have the requirement that `T` implement a certain interface (ie, that it has an `isEmpty()` function). Until then, you can't avoid polymorphism if what you want is to avoid code duplication by sharing a set of common functions (re: interface) between different classes. That's one of the main reasons to use [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) in the first place.

With that said, you are looking for the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) like Igor Tandetnik mentioned in the comments. This allows you to share common code between classes *without* the runtime penalty of virtual functions (runtime polymorphism). Using CRTP lets the compiler do that stuff for you.

Using a simple base class:

```
template <typename T>
struct ICountable {
    bool isEmpty() const { return static_cast<T*>(this)->_getCount() == 0; }
};
```

And then your derived list:

```
class LinkedList : public ICountable<LinkedList> {
    int _getCount() const { return size; }
};
```

Any class that derives from `ICountable` in this way will now have an `isEmpty()` method that uses the implementation-specific `_getCount()` method without the use of virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

With templates, you just imply the interface. You write a function template and require that the type you pass in meets your criteria. In this case, just:

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething(T const& countable) {
    if (countable.empty()) {
         doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

All the C++ standard containers have an `empty()` method, and you could do worse than copy the standard interfaces for containers that you write yourself. This function already works for `vector` and `list` and `string` and ..., all without any dynamic dispatch overhead or without the OOP requirements of having to inherit from some interface.

Generic programming works if the types have the interface you need - they don't need to inherit from all the correct named interfaces to get them.

Comment: let me elaborate a bit on your answer - yes I am doing something like a copy of standard containers, but mine is much more simplified and specialized, so there is no comparison between the two. I never checked the the `empty()` function of standard containers, but I think best way is to write `empty()` once, instead to have it in every container?

Comment: @Nick Standard containers have a dedicated `empty()` method because it often can be implemented more efficiently than `size() == 0`. In particular, `std::list::size()` is (or at least, used to be, in prior versions of the standard) allowed to have O(N) complexity.